# Mouse-Click Movement Using Unity NavMeshAgent Causes Stuttering Upon Reaching Destination

Tags: unity, c#, movement, navmesh

Alrighty, so I've seen a lot of stuttering-related questions about `NavMeshAgents` but my problem is a little specific to my use case since it has nothing to do with `NavMesh` itself as a system. The system works great for me, it's simply a problem with how I am implementing it. I'm sure there is a solution, I'm just not sure what it is.

So, onto the actual issue. I am using `NavMesh` and `NavMeshAgents` to facilitate a mouse-click style movement system (think **Diablo** or **Path of Exile**). When the mouse is held down, the player will constantly move towards that location using a `Raycast` from the camera to the `NavMesh` to get and set the destination.

However, despite using the `stoppingDistance` variable on `NavMeshAgents`, it doesn't matter because if the player holds down the mouse button near the threshold of the stopping distance, the character will constantly switch states between *destination reached* to *new destination found*.

My code is a bit messy, so apologies for that, this is a quickly thrown together prototype of my movement system. That being said, I don't actually think my code is the problem, I think this is simply a very niche problem I don't know how to solve.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask navigableMask;
    
    private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    private Camera _followCamera;

    private void Start()
    {
        _followCamera = Camera.main;
        _agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMovement();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        movementInput.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        movementInput.Disable();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        if (movementInput.ReadValue<float>() == 1f)
        {
            Ray ray = _followCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 100, navigableMask))
            {
                Move(hit.point);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Move(Vector3 destination)
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(destination);
    }
}
```

Here is a gif of the problem, in action.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem you could solve with a bit of [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

While the mouse button is held:

- If the character is already in the current stopping distance, change the stopping distance to a "large" distance (so that they don't start moving from a small mouse move - they'll let it get a little farther away before chasing).
- If the character is *not* already in the current stopping distance, change the stopping distance to a "small" distance (so that they have some room to move without stopping short after only half a step).

This can still create some stop-and-start, but by tuning the sizes of the large and small distances, you can change it from jerky hesitation to a more deliberate-looking pause & run to catch up.

Comment: I'll give this a try and mark this as solved if it works. This is the exact type of answer I was hoping for!

Comment: Marked as solution! Worked like a charm and was extremely easy to implement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it! This kind of hysteresis tends to work well for the whole family of problems of "flickery/jittery inconsistent behaviour near a trigger threshold", so it's a good general-purpose tool to have in your kit. 